# The name `instance' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class NetManager : MonoBehaviour
{   
        // URL can be also locale : "file://C:\file.xml"
        private static string URL = "http://www.domain.com/file.xml";

        private XMLManager.Player player = null;

        void Start() {
            StartCoroutine (instance.RetrieveNextPlayerCoroutine (callback));
        }

        // ----------- Retrieve Player -------------- //

        public delegate void RetrieveNextPlayerCallback (XMLManager.Player result);

        private IEnumerator RetrieveNextPlayerCoroutine (RetrieveNextPlayerCallback callback)
        {
                WWW www = new WWW (URL);
                yield return www;
                if (www.error == null) {
                        player = XMLManager.ParsePlayerXML (www.text);
                } else { 
                        Debug.Log (www.error);
                }
        }
}
```

I've been given an xml parser to use for unity.. I am receiving this error, and I'm not sure how to solve it.. any suggestions would help :/

Comment: Well yes - you're calling `instance.RetrieveNextPlayerCoroutine` - but you don't have a variable called `instance`.

Comment: When posting code, please post it on this site instead of linking to an external site that contains the code.  I edited your post to move the code here.

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: @JohnKoerner - Apologies

Comment: @SLaks - I was just given this and I was told to just plug it in and use it, I didn't write it, and I'm not to familiar with C#,  so I don't really know whats going on here

Comment: here's a guessfix: if you removed ": MonoBehaviour" from the class declaration re-add it, otherwise try remove "instance." where you call StartCoroutine.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `instance` in the `Start` method is never declared, which is exactly what the error is telling you.